# find corresponding point in a rotated image

Tags: math, rotational-matrices

I need help transforming a selected point in the Rotated View back to it's corresponding point in the original Image. So for example if I clicked in the upper left ( 0,0 ) in the rotated view, it should correspond to (0,1280) in the original image.

**Extra points for a solution that works regardless of the rotation.**

```
Original Image ( 1920 x 1280 )     Rotated View ( for display on phone )
+----------------------------+     +-----------------+
|(0,0)                       |     |(0,0)            |  ( 1280 x 1920 )
|                            |     |                 |
|                            |     |       x         |
|    x                       |     |    ( click )    |
|    ( what is this point )  |     |                 |
|                            |     |                 |
|                            |     |                 |
+----------------------------+     |                 |
                      (1920,1280)  |                 |
                                   |                 |
                                   |                 |
                                   |                 |
                                   |                 |
                                   |                 |
                                   |                 |
                                   |                 |
                                   +-----------------+
                                                      (1280,1920)
```

**UPDATED**

```
    /*
    This is how I build the matrix used to perform the initial rotation from the original to     the rotated image. This matrix also includes scaling 

    Code base: Android/Java
    bitmap ( bitmap i'm scaling/rotating )
    canvas ( the canvas being drawn to )

    Note: bitmap is in landscape mode / canvas is in portrait

    */

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    float centerX = canvas.getWidth() >> 1;
    float centerY = canvas.getHeight() >> 1;

    rAngle = 90;
    scaleH = ((float) canvas.getHeight()) / bitmap.getWidth();
    scaleW = ((float) canvas.getWidth()) / bitmap.getHeight();

    scaler.preScale(scaleH, scaleW);
    scaler.postRotate(rAngle, centerY, centerX);

    float nx = (canvas.getHeight() - canvas.getWidth()) / 2;
    scaler.postTranslate(-nx, nx);

    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap,scaler,null);
```

I'm hardly a math guy, so any hand holding will be appreciated. :)

Comment: I think you need to at least label the coordinates of the the corners of your rectangles. I'm a bit confused as to why the top-right corner on one rectangle would be (0, 0) while it's (0, 1280) in the other. (Or maybe it's the top-left. I'm not sure.)

Comment: my apologies,I meant to say upper-left is ( 0,0) in the rotated view. I updated my post to reflect this.

Comment: What do you know about the rotation? If you have the rotation matrix, you can simply transform the point from the rotated image with the inverse of this rotation matrix....

Comment: @Marco13 This will work, but you have to remember to translate by the maximum Y-coordinate afterwards. Otherwise you end up with negative Y values.

Comment: if anyone can provide me the formula to use would be great! The problem i'm having now is that i do get negative numbers when I just simply try to rotate my point by 90 degrees around the center of the "rotated view" I can post the numbers I get after my rotation to see if i'm close or on the right track if that'll help.

Comment: Sure, post your current rotation matrix.

Comment: i updated my post with my code that performs the original transformation from original to rotated. ( maybe some help in inverting the process will solve my problem )

Comment: i think i was able to solve my problem. i used this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/7418428/1116784 so that I could perform an inverse of my initial matrix. Thanks @Marco13 for pointing me in the right direction on this one.

Answer (score 1):

Subscript `O` indicates coordinates in the original frame and subscript `R` in the rotated frame:

> X<sub>O</sub> = Y<sub>R</sub>
>   Y<sub>O</sub> = maxX<sub>R</sub> - X<sub>R</sub>

The four corners of the frame give us:

For top-left in the rotated frame (0,0)

> X<sub>O</sub> = 0
>   Y<sub>O</sub> = 1279 - 0 = 1279
>   (0, 1279)

For top-right, (1279, 0):

> X<sub>O</sub> = 0
>   Y<sub>O</sub> = 1279 - 1279 = 0
>   (0, 0)

For bottom-left, (0, 1919):

> X<sub>O</sub> = 1919
>   Y<sub>O</sub> = 1279 - 0 = 1279
>   (1919, 1279)

For bottom-right, (1279, 1919):

> X<sub>O</sub> = 1919
>   Y<sub>O</sub> = 1279 - 1279 = 0
>   (1919, 0)